# ST3, SendTextPlus to R and Python

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

How do I have Sublime Text 3 send code to R or Python (via Terminal) *depending on which language I'm writing in*?

My instinct is use SendTextPlus (STP).  Currently, I have that package configured so that command+enter sends the selected lines to R; if R is not open, it launches R.  I would like for ST3/STP to recognize when I am in a Python file, send the selected lines to Terminal and open iPython if necessary, without me using a different key binding.  Alternatively, I could program a different key binding, but I am not having luck with the user settings.

I tried to follow [the example from STP's Readme](https://github.com/randy3k/SendTextPlus), to no avail.  Below are my user settings for STP.

> {
>       // path to tmux and screen (linux/mac)
>       // "tmux" : "tmux",
>       // "screen" : "screen",
>
> ```
> // path to Rgui.exe (for windows only)
> // "R32" : "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.0\\bin\\i386\\Rgui.exe",
> // "R64" : "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.0\\bin\\x64\\Rgui.exe",
>
> // auto advance to the next line.
> "auto_advance" : true,
>
> // auto advance to the next non-empty line. Override to false if "auto_advance" is false.
> "auto_advance_non_empty": false,
>
> // prog could be Terminal, iTerm, Cmder, Cygwin, tmux, screen,
> // SublimeREPL; It could also be RStudio, Chrome-RStudio, Chrome-Jupyter,
> // Safari-RStudio, Safari-Jupyter.
> // the order matters, SendText+ will pick the first match out of the list.
>
> "defaults" : [
>     {
>         "platform": "osx",
>         "prog": "R"
>     },
>     {
>         "platform": "windows",
>         "prog": "Cmder"
>     },
>     {
>         "platform": "linux",
>         "prog": "tmux"
>     },
>     {"platform": "osx",
>     "scopes": ["source.python"],
>     "prog": "Terminal"}
> ],
>
> // enable or disable SendText+ keybinds
> "send_text_plus_keybinds": true,
>
> "keys": ["super+shift+a"], "command": "send_text_plus",
> "args": {"cmd": "source(\"$selection\")"},
> "context": [
>     { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python" }
> ]
> ```
>
> }